# How to Cut video clip and convert from .avi to .mp4 in a fast way

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

Here is my command

```
C:\Users\Example\Desktop>E:\OUTPUT\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i F:\BackUp\movie.avi -ss 4000 -t 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

**I am trying to cut and convert a movie.avi file from 4000(starting duration in sec) to 60 sec**

**If my starting duration will be 0 or within 100 the process will complete faster if it more than 2000 its taking long time**

suggest me any other command to make this fast.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a fast seek:

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 4000 -t 60 -i F:\BackUp\movie.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```